# Nonhomogeneous equation involving logarithm

Tags: special-functions

This is probably a lame question, but what is the general approach to solving $\log z +z \sigma +1=0$ for $z$? Wolfram Alpha obtains a Lambert W-function, but I don't quite see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\sigma\neq 0$, you need something like Lambert's W function.

Taking exponentials of both sides, we have
$$\begin{align*}
e^{\log z + z\sigma + 1} &= 1\\
e^{\log z}e^{\sigma z} e&= 1\\
ze^{\sigma z}&= \frac{1}{e}\\
\sigma ze^{\sigma z} &= \frac{\sigma}{e}
\end{align*}$$
Now let $x=\sigma z$. Then the equation is equivalent to
$$xe^x = \frac{\sigma}{e},$$
which means that $x=W(\frac{\sigma}{e})$, hence
$$z = \frac{x}{\sigma} = \frac{1}{\sigma} W\left(\frac{\sigma}{e}\right).$$

(If $\sigma=0$, then you just have $\log z + 1 = 0$, or $z=e^{-1}$.)

Comment: This is kinda hard, is there any intuition behind W-function? At least of what order is it?

Comment: The $W$ function is, in a sense, a "magic" function. We know that $g(x) = xe^x$ is one-to-one when $x\geq e^{-1}$, so we know it has an inverse; $W$ is that inverse. As "magical", in a way, as the $\arcsin$ function. I'm not sure what you mean by "order" of the function.

Comment: @sigma: I don't think that's a valid equation for the exponential (though I guess it works very near zero...); anyway, the Taylor series for $W$ around $0$ is $$W(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!}x^n.$$

Comment: yes you are right. I mean $e^x=1+x+O(x^2)$